# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$ converges, then finding the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a/n}^{b/n} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R$. It has a property that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$ converges. I have to find the value of
$$(1) \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a/n}^{b/n} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$$ and $$(2) \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_t^n \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}dx\right)$$

I firstly thought of mean value theorem in integral, and I wanted to calculate
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{c\to 0^+}\frac{f(c)}{c} {1\over n}$$  which was derived from the fact that
$$\exists c\in \text{between} \ \ \ \ {a\over n}, {b\over n} \ \ \ \ s.t. \ \ \ \frac{1}{{a\over n}-{b\over n}}\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a/n}^{b/n} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx = \frac{f(c)}{c}$$
I tried to calculate it using squeeze and the inequality that
$${f(c)\over b}<\frac{f(c)}{c}{1\over n}<{f(c)\over a}$$ assuming that a<b by WLOG  but the value is not still determined. To solve (2), I realized that I have to first solve (1), so I need some help for (1). Any hint of solution is going to be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's odd about this question is that we are given information about f (x) for x>1 and yet question 1 involves x close to zero.

Comment: For 1), as $n$ gets large $f(x)$ can be arbitrarily well approximated by $f(0)$ over $[a/n, b/n]$.